# How to receive compressed JSON data using XMLHttpRequest from a java server

Tags: java, json, xmlhttprequest, embedded-jetty

I am requesting and parsing json data using XMLHttpRequest. A java 8 server using embedded jetty 9 receives the request and returns the data. The code is shown below with the client side javascript in the first block and the server side java code in the second.

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    }
  }
};
http.open("GET", "/mydata", true);
http.send();
```

---

```
 public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

  response.setContentType("application/json");
  response.setStatus(Response.SC_OK);
  PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
  pw.write(myDataInJsonStringFormat);
  pw.close();
  baseRequest.setHandled(true);
}
```

Question is how can I modify the above code to send compressed json data from java and then decompress the data using XMLHttpRequest ?

I would prefer not to use any additional client or server side libraries over what I am already using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the same data sets are being served repeatedly to clients. Rather than adding a jetty handler, the json text string is converted to a gzipped byte array:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(gzip, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
osw.write(myDataInJsonStringFormat);
osw.close();

compressedJsonData = bos.toByteArray();
```

The data is then returned to the java client by the jetty handler:

```
public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

  response.setContentType("application/json");
  response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
  response.setContentLength(compressedJsonData .length);

  response.setStatus(Response.SC_OK);

  response.getOutputStream().write(compressedJsonData );
  response.getOutputStream().close();

  baseRequest.setHandled(true);
}
```

In the *XMLHttpRequest* javascript code on the client side no change is necessary. Browsers (verified on Edge, IE11, Chrome) automatically decompress the json and convert it back to text before passing it to *this.responseText* :

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    }
  }
};
http.open("GET", "/mydata", true);
http.send();
```

I also added a progress bar to show a client how much data has been downloaded. For this the length prior to compression is saved and added as a custom http header on the server side

```
response.setHeader("Uncompressed-Length", myDataInJsonStringFormat.length + "");
```

On the client this header is read in the *onreadystatechange* handler as *estimatedLength* when *readyState == 2* and a progress handler set up as follows:

```
    http.onprogress = function(event) {
      var percentComplete = Math.round((event.loaded/estimatedLength) * 100);
      progressMessage = Math.round(event.loaded/1000) + "KB downloaded and uncompressed, " + percentComplete + "%";
    };
```

Comment: If you use the Jetty `GzipHandler` then it honors the various cache headers between the browser, any intermediary, your Jetty server, and any servlets that set those headers.  The approach you have in this answer does not.  Your content will be repeatedly compressed (when it doesn't need to be) and repeatedly sent to the client (when it doesn't need to be).

Comment: Perhaps I should have added that I send headers   response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public,max-age=1209600"); // 2 weeks and response.setHeader("Expires", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1209600000).toString()); but I omitted this as the question was about compression. The content is cached properly in both service workers and browser caches and this has been verified by monitoring server logs and not seeing fresh requests.

Comment: Yeah, old school cache management.  Keep in mind that GzipHandler also supports ETag and range requests (for when you eventually want/need them)

Comment: Thanks for tip, ETag could work well with my particular implementation and is something may well use down the line

Answer (score 1):

You can use base64 to transport the data. In there are two functions respectively for decoding and encoding base64 strings: atob() and btoa(). Search how you can do this using java.

Comment: While this can be done on both the java and javascript sides would it not increase the size of the json data as suggested by the example at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_atob.asp

Comment: The data I am sending form the java server to client will be up to 17MB in size and this often over a poor mobile connection.

Comment: In this case you can use JSONC to compress the JSON String:

JSONC.compress( json );
JSONC.decompress( compressedJSON );

Answer (score 0):

Add the Eclipse Jetty `GzipHandler` to your server handler tree in a place before your custom Handler code.

That will perform 2 tasks:

- It will uncompress incoming compressed request body content
- It will compress outgoing response body content

Just make sure you configure the list of included mime-types on the GzipHandler to allow `application/json` to be processed on the response body content.

Comment: If I can set this up, what do I do with the compressed data in the XMLHttpRequest response ?

Comment: Nothing needed to be done in the XMLHttpResponse data, see below. This answer would have been the server side approach taken if the json data to be returned was dynamically changing rather than more static in nature.